# test case for form validation not running in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I started learning django framework in that I have created form which verifies interdependent fields. now I have written a testCase for it but my console is showing 0 test cases ran.I am not getting why it is not running

below is my forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fromDate=forms.DateField()
    toDate=forms.DateField(required=False)
    fromLocation=forms.CharField()
    toLocation=forms.CharField()
    def clean(self):
        """verify from and to date and location"""
        cleanedData=super().clean()
        fLocation=cleanedData.get('fromLocation')
        tLocation=cleanedData.get('toLocation')
        self.validateLocation(fLocation,tLocation)
        self.validateDates(self.fromDate,self.toDate)

    def validateLocation(self,fLocation,tLocation):
        if fLocation==tLocation:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("from and to location can not be same"),code="invalid location")

    def validateDates(self,fromDate,toDate):
        if toDate is not None:
            if toDate <= fromDate:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("from date should be less than to date"),code="invalid date")
```

and my tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase

from booking.forms import SearchForm

# Create your tests here.
class SearchTestCase(TestCase):
    def fromToLocationSameTestCase(self):
        form_data={'fromLocation':'bangalore','toLocation':'bangalore','fromDate':'2017-06-07'}
        form=SearchForm(data=form_data)
        self.assertFlase(form.is_valid())
```

please let me know where I went wrong. FYI I tried by overriding clean method of forms but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All test methods need to begin with `test_`. (And in any case, standard Python naming convention for methods is `lower_case_with_underscore`.)

Call your method `test_from_to_location_same`.